# Passing variables through Selenium send.keys instead of strings

Tags: python, selenium

I'm trying to use Selenium for some app testing, and I need it to plug a variable in when filling a form instead of a hardcoded string. IE:

this works
`name_element.send_keys("John Doe")`
but this doesnt
`name_element.send_keys(username)`

Does anyone know how I can accomplish this? Pretty big Python noob, but used Google extensively to try and find out.

Answer (score 3):

In at least one case, I found that I couldn't pass a variable to send_keys unless I first passed a regular empty string:

```
inputElement.send_keys("")
inputElement.send_keys(my_text_variable)
```

It also works as a list:

`inputElement.send_keys("", my_text_variable)`

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
username = r'John Doe'

name_element.send_keys(username)
```

I was able to pass the string without casting it just fine in my test.

Answer (score 0):

I dont understand...why not just set username="John Doe" I'm having trouble figuring out what you want to do beyond that

```
username ="John Doe"

def some_function():
   name_element.send_keys(username)
```

Comment: I can confirm: using the Python libraries to access Selenium, this doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

Have you made certain that your variable is a string?

Greg's answer would ensure that.  If you're not completely sure, you could try

```
name_element.send_keys(str(username))
```

Answer (score 0):

I think username might be a variable in the python library you are using. Try calling it something else like Username1 and see if it works??

Answer (score 0):

I got it! Just use:

```
var1 = ''.join(otherVariable)
inputElement.send_keys(var1)
```